how to: gradient on inside border of container, but so container contents remain visible
Does anyone know how to create this specific kind of gradient overlay (when you hover over the type) https://bboxtype.com/typefaces/?filter=FFF
One that appears inside around the edges (from all sides) with gradual fade  - so the contents of the div can be seen clearly.
I've tried it a few different ways, incl on the border itself but can't seem to replicate this look that has that fade in from all sides. Any ideas?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,122,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,122,0,0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.box:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gradient Rollover Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="grey">

<div class="box"></div>

</body>
</html>




This is implemented using box-shadow inset instead of a gradient. You can check out the modified demo below to see it in action:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      background: white;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
      box-shadow: rgb(255, 105, 180) 0px 0px 40px 0px inset;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gradient Rollover Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>




Edit after requested by OP, you can use CSS custom properties to customise the color of the box as illustrated below:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      background: white;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
      box-shadow: var(--glow-color) 0px 0px 40px 0px inset;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gradient Rollover Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
  <div class="box" style="--glow-color: red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="--glow-color: green"></div>
</body>

</html>




this is perfect, thank you for the tip!

hi @angyc - do you know if there's a way to use the code once, but set different colours for different divs? (so you dont have to repeat it each time?)

@hellofromlondon yes there is, you can consider using CSS custom properties to achieve this. While this should be a separate question, I have edited my answer above to include this.
